# Had requestAnimationFrame kill the setInterval?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, requestanimationframe

Is it right to say, as for 2016,
That using setInterval is obsolete and should always be replaced with a setInterval function?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No;

---

Long Answer:

Using `setInterval` as a mean to calculate anything related to UI updates for the next frame or to schedule animation-related functions (i.e. running a function every 16.6ms) ; Yes it is obselete, replace with `requestanimationframe`;

But using `setInterval` on its own use-cases (e.g. polling for some event every two seconds), probably with high intervals (e.g. every 10s) which has nothing to do with 
the very frame to be rendered Shouldn't be replaced with `requestAnimationFrame`.